# How much compensation should I ask for, when I prepared to move out of state, but employer changed plans 3 days before I was supposed to leave

Tags: compensation

My employer asked me to move my family out to Chicago for 4 months to run a project for them. Then 3 days before I was going to leave they decided to change their plan. I found housing in Chicago that I have to cancel. My wife and I packed our entire house, luckily my current landlord is going to let us stay. I would have been able to save about $10,000 while being there since they were going to pay my rent. My question is how much should I ask for all the effort and inconvenience my wife and I have been through? Also how do I word it? Thanks!

Comment: Your employer asked you to move your family out? You mean he asked you to move and offered to help relocating (temporarily) your family? Please clarify; the question is confusing.

Comment: The amount that you would have saved does not figure. However, the amount you spent without getting recovery does.

Comment: My employer said they would cover my moving expenses, both there and back. They were also going to pay for my rent while me and my family was there. Sorry if that was confusing. My question is how much should I ask for, for the time and effort that went into the planning? Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I was relocated by my formal employer three times (twice international, once domestic). .Every time I received MOU before I moved myself and my family. Do you have MOU or any kind of such document?

Comment: The employer offering to pay rent at the temporary location is consistent with the OP being expected to retain their current residence. The intent would be to cover the additional cost of a temporary residence for three months, not to hand the OP a $10,000 bonus.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to be taken seriously by them(after all you re supposed to be in the same team and not against each other) ask only for the actual costs inquired from this. Ie if you paid some advance for the new housing, cancellation fees for schooling for your children there etc. Asking for compensation about time spent planning this on your behalf is almost certainly guaranteed to come out in a bad way for you. Asking for compensation about money you would save that you would normally pay as your current rent would automatically make you seem like a greedy,erratic person and aleniate your employer and with good damn reason if I may say so.

p.s. as someone asked for in a comment already, did he agree on helping your family relocate alongside you or it was just insinuated/taken for granted by you? If the latter then I suggest not asking to be compensated anything outside your general own expenses paid already by you in regards to this move.